# Calculating indefinite integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

I want to calculate
$$I_n = \int \frac{d\theta}{\sin^n(c\theta)\cdot \cos(c\theta)}. $$
The answer is 
$$-\frac{1}{c(n-1)\sin^{n-1}(c\theta)}+ \int\frac{d\theta}{\sin^{n-2}(c\theta)\cdot\cos(c\theta)}.$$
I started on this way:
$$ I_n = \frac{1}{c} \int \frac{c\cdot \cos (c\theta) \, d\theta}{\sin^n(c\theta) \cdot \cos(c\theta)} = \frac{1}{c} \int \frac{dt}{t^n \cdot (1-t^2)},$$
being $t=\sin(c\theta)$.

Am I on the correct way? Any suggestions and hints? Thanks a lot!

Comment: For something similar, see [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=c\theta$, $dt =c d\theta$ to get $I_n=\frac{1}{c}\int\csc^{n}t\sec t dt$.

Now let $u=\sec t\csc^{n-2}t, dv=\csc^{2}t dt$, so that

$du=[\sec t\tan t\csc^{n-2}t+\sec t[(n-2)\csc^{n-3}t\;(-\csc t\cot t)]dt, \;\;v=-\cot t$,

to get $cI_n=-\sec t\csc^{n-2}t\cot t+\int\sec t\csc^{n-2}t\;dt-(n-2)\int\sec t \csc^{n-2}t\cot^{2}t\; dt$

$=-\csc^{n-1}t+\int\sec t\csc^{n-2}t\;dt-(n-2)\int\sec t\csc^{n-2}t(\csc^{2}t-1)\;dt$

$=-\csc^{n-1}t+(n-1)\int\sec t\csc^{n-2}t\;dt-(n-2)cI_n$.

Then $(n-1)cI_n=-\csc^{n-1}t+(n-1)\int\sec t\csc^{n-2}t \;dt$,

so $\displaystyle I_n=-\frac{\csc^{n-1}(c\theta)}{c(n-1)}+\int\sec (c\theta)\csc^{n-2}(c\theta)\; d\theta$.

Comment: At last line your answer differs with the answer that I put when I asked my question. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment; I have tried to correct my errors.